# does a san improve application speed?

Tags: storage-area-network

Our lead tech wants a SAN.

We have 2 -2950's and 2- 1950's.  all dual quad core, 73gb 15K drives, 16gb each. 8 drives on DB each and 4 drives on WS each.

our application is based on .net 2.0 running on iis 6.

I understand having a san will help with a quick restore in terms of DR, but will it actually increase the speed of our app?

what will give us the fastest bang for the buck if not a san?

Comment: The real question is: do you have the skill set to manage a SAN? Virtualized storage is great for many reasons, but the learning curve for these and other associated technologies is fairly steep.

Comment: i do not currenlty, but i read a dell md3000 is not that hard to manage once set up properly. 15 x 146gb is what had been proposed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hard drive speed and quantity is only a small piece of the disk performance picture. You also need to look at your workload characteristics, caching configuration, disk alignment, RAID array type (1+0 vs. 5/6), segment size/stripe width, and whether you're inadvertently mixing random/sequential workloads (or multiple sequential workloads) on the same set of spindles in such a way that it drags your application performance. If you can't get these basics down on local disk, a SAN is unlikely to help you besides providing you with the ability to add more spindles (disks) to service your I/O requests.

A SAN represents a significant initial cash outlay, a significant yearly support/maintenance fee, a significant amount of supporting infrastructure (iSCSI/Fibre Channel), and a significant amount of learning to support correctly. Unless you're really sure you need one, you should probably exhaust all the other ways of improving your application's performance first.

Comment: so you are saying perform a audit with all the above metrics first to determine if a san would help? we run raid 5 now, but looking to move to raid 10 in the future.

Comment: RAID-5 is probably not a bad fit for read-heavy workloads like on most web servers (unless you're prone to failing disks; degraded arrays don't perform well). However, RAID-5 is atrocious at writes unless your application is really predictable and you really know what you're doing tuning it. RAID-10 is much better-performing all around and your database in particular should see much better handling of operations like index updates.

Answer (score 1):

A SAN can provide performance increase but is not a magic cure all. You need to look at some detailed performance metrics to determine the reason for the slow behavior. Check out perfmon and go from there.